# Where can I download JApplet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am trying to make a Java applet. So far I have this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Applet extends JApplet {

public void start(){}

public void init(){}

public void paint(Graphics g){}
```

}

But I get this message: javax.swing.JApplet is not present in JRE Emulation Library

Also this message: java.awt.Graphics is not present JRE Emulation Library

If I change the import statements to the following:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
```

I still get the same message.

I have come across many links but nothing gives me the option to download javax.swing.JApplet and java.awt.Graphics to get my applet to work

Comment: `javax.swing.JApplet` is part of the core Java library, you don't download it separatly

Comment: What are you trying to run Java with?  I've never heard of a 'JRE Emulation Library' in an error message.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) Are you sure the IDE is set up for J2SE development as opposed to (for instance) Android?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found out that even though the applet was showing an error it would still run and show the applet